# Why won't these buttons within navbar align right with justify-content-end?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have created a navbar with bootstrap. I want the two buttons to align right, but no matter what I apply justify-content-end to, it doesn't work.

My understanding is that d-flex will need to be applied to the container, and then justify-content-end to the items as required, but using that logic (applying it to the navbar div), it doesn't work.

here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/MH092/pen/xxXwzVY

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand pr-5" href="#">40k QuickLore</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex pl-1" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class=" nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link pr-5" href="#">WTF is 40k</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Imperium
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Xenos
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Misc
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button">RIGHT ME</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button">RIGHT ME</button>
                    </form>
                </nav>
```

Comment: The problem is that you have your `form` inside `<li class="nav-item dropdown">` which has a very small width. Give it `width:100%`. Also give `<form class="form-inline">`  `width:100%; justify-content: flex-end;`.

Comment: If you make a second `<ul class="navbar-nav">` and add `ml-auto` to the class it might work. I do think you are adding problems buy having `nav` inside `nav`.

Comment: You're missing a few closing </li>s. I'd also suggest not including a nav inside of your nav. Here's a revised codepen with modifications only to its html: https://codepen.io/maggiecody/pen/poWjZmG

Comment: @JKK No problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: flex;` to you nav-item class and your "right me" divs will be on the right.

But if you want them to be at the very right, you have to change your DOM structure a bit because "right me" are in a `li` tag wich is not their right place.

I think you should have this structure:
[image]

and then add     `justify-content: space-between;` to your parent [image]

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few closing `</li>` tags. I'd also suggest not including a `nav` inside of your `nav`. Here's a revised codepen with modifications only to your html: [codepen.io/maggiecody/pen/poWjZmG](http://codepen.io/maggiecody/pen/poWjZmG).